# Why does my Asus PB277Q screen keep waking up while the Mac it is connected to is sleeping?

Tags: macos, display, high-sierra, sleep-wake

Whenever I put my Macbook Pro running High Sierra to sleep my Asus PB277Q keeps waking up displaying a blue screen saying 'HDMI no signal' every few seconds, forever. Some other times it sleeps normally, and I can't tell what is causing the behavior.

From what I can tell the Mac itself is asleep. It makes no sound, Bluetooth is off, Wake for network access is off, sharing (internet for example) is off, removing USB devices changes nothing. The screen is connected to a Displayport to HDMI/DVI/VGA adapter, which in turn is connected to the screen over an HDMI cable.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: It sounds like this may be a question about the behavior of your particular monitor, rather than about your Mac. Does this only happen with your MacBook Pro, or only after the upgrade to macOS High Sierra?

Comment: It looks like it really might be an issue with the screen: I just plugged it into a different Mac running Sierra and had the same issue. It seems to not happen if I plug it in directly via HDMI, but the Mac I use doesn't have this port. Any ideas what I could to to solve this? From the options I can choose from the screen's menu there doesn't seem to be anything of much help.

Answer (score 1):

This is because this monitor is for 75 hz but in high sierra or later I think this feature not work good now, I have this monitor and I have this problem, but you can use this monitor with your make, you go to display settings, select this monitor and change HZ 75 to 60 and it's works good.